# Using Serilog Seq sink gives me Event JSON representation exceeds the body size limit 262144;

Tags: serilog, datalust-seq

At some point in the code, I need to specify a huge JSON , I've got my logs full of

`Event JSON representation exceeds the body size limit 262144; sample:` .

On Seq part I've changed the settings to allowing 1Mb but I still got this error message. Should I also change the web application part?

Is there a setting I can pass in the appsettings.configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The limit needs to be changed both in the `WriteTo.Seq()` call's `eventBodyLimitBytes` argument, and on the Seq server in Settings > System > Raw event body limit.

Comment: Hello, it's fine to define it as

```
  "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "https://xxx",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "eventBodyLimitBytes": 10485760
        }
        }
    ],
```